# Load a external image in a Ext.Js Window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to know how to load a external image e.g. http://www.google.co.za/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png into a new ExtJs window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the only content in the EXTjs Window then you can set it using the html option in the window configuration. Something like this

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    html: '<img src="http://www.google.co.za/intl/en%5Fcom/images/logo%5Fplain.png" />',
    height: 150,
    width: 250
});
```

If there are more contents in the window then you can add the html to the html property of the container for the image

now it showing perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please take a close look at `body` property documentation:

> **body : Ext.Element**
>
> The Panel's body Element which may be
>   used to contain HTML content. The
>   content may be specified in the html
>   config, or it may be loaded using the
>   autoLoad config, or through the
>   Panel's Updater. Read-only. If this is
>   used to load visible HTML elements in
>   either way, then the Panel may not be
>   used as a Layout for hosting nested
>   Panels. If this Panel is intended to
>   be used as the host of a Layout (See
>   layout then the body Element must not
>   be loaded or changed - it is under the
>   control of the Panel's Layout.